# asp.net vb - onclick event on bootstrap table row not triggering code-behind function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a function that create bootstrap table on the fly using string builder. And now I want to add onclick event that trigger a code-behind function. I already add the onclick event on the **TR** but when I clicked it, nothing happens. here's the complete code :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

   Dim sContent  As New StringBuilder
   Dim sParam as new string = Request.Querystring("p")

   sContent.AppendLine("<table class='table table-hover table-striped table-condensed table-responsive table-bordered'>")
   sContent.AppendLine("<tr style='cursor: pointer;' onclick='viewDetail('" & sParam & "')>")
   sContent.AppendLine("<td style='width:10%;text-align:center'>" & startTime & "</td>")
   sContent.AppendLine("<td style='width:10%;text-align:center'>" & matchStatus & "</td>")
   sContent.AppendLine("<td style='width:30%;text-align:right'>" & sHomeName & "</td>")
   sContent.AppendLine("<td style='width:5%;text-align:center;font-weight:bold'>" & sResultFT & "</td>")
   sContent.AppendLine("<td style='width:30%;text-align:left'>" & sAwayName & "</td>")
   sContent.AppendLine("<td style='width:5%;text-align:center'>" & sResultHT & "</td>")
   sContent.AppendLine("<td style='width:10%'></td>")
   sContent.AppendLine("</tr>")
   sContent.AppendLine("</table>")

   Response.Write(sContent.ToString)
End Sub



Protected Sub viewDetail(ByVal sPar as String)

   '====Here's the code===    

End Sub
```

I add the **onclick='viewDetail'** on the **TR** section of the table, but it didn't trigger the viewDetail. Did I missed something ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Function `viewDetail` is a server function. But event `onclick` in `tr` is a client function.

You can call by ajax for this case.

Comment: you can read from here, so detail http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/531473/callplusfunctionplusinplus